# Modificar objecto javascript

Tags: javascript

estoy intentado modificar un objeto para que me quede con el siguiente formato:

```
["Antena" : "red", "Antena FM" : "red", "Antena TV" : "red", "Antena GSM" : "red", "Antena LTE" : "red", "Antena WCDMA" : "red", "Arquitectura de transmisión" : "red", "Antena" : "red"]
```

Pero lo único que consigo es algo como esto:

```
["Antena: red", "Antena FM: red", "Antena TV: red", "Antena GSM: red", "Antena LTE: red", "Antena WCDMA: red", "Arquitectura de transmisión: red", "Antena: red"]
```

El código que lo genera es:

```
var names = filtrados.map(function(x) { return x['Nombre'] + ": red"});
```

¿Cómo hago para que quede de la manera deseada?

Comment: ¿Lo que intentas obtener es un único objeto con propiedades Antena, Antena FM, Antena TV,... y que todas las propiedades tengan valor "red"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No me queda del todo claro si lo que intentas conseguir es un único objeto con las propiedades definidas en la variable *filtrados*, todas ellas con valor *"red"*:

```js
$(function(){
  var filtrados = [
    {Nombre: "Antena"},
    {Nombre: "Antena TV"},
    {Nombre: "Antena GSM"},
    {Nombre: "Antena LTE"},
    {Nombre: "Antena WCDMA"},
    {Nombre: "Arquitectura de trasmisión"},
    {Nombre: "Antena"}
  ];

  var names = {};
  filtrados.forEach(function(x) { names[x["Nombre"]] = "red"; });
  $(".resultado").text(JSON.stringify(names));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="resultado"></span>
```

Comment: Es así como lo comentas, tu código me funciono a la perfección, gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Un array de objetos tiene esta forma, fíjate en las llaves:

```
[ {"Antena" : "red"}, {"Antena FM" : "red"} ... ]
```

Entonces en tu código:

```
var names = filtrados.map(function(x) { return { [x['Nombre']]: "red" }; });
```

Tienes que devolver un objeto por cada item, pero el detalle está que el nombre de la propiedad de cada objeto es variable, es por esto que se usa `[]` alrededor de `x['Nombre']`.

Si lo que quieres es un solo objeto donde cada propiedad proviene del array a manera de diccionario entonces:

```
var names = filtrados.reduce(function(prev, current) {
    prev[current.Nombre] = 'red'; 
    return prev; 
}, { });
```

Comment: Con el código propuesto me arroja un arreglo con múltiples objetos, algo así:                                                                                                        Array [ Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object ]

Comment: ¿Entonces quieres un objeto con múltiples propiedades?

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar asi:

```
var customList = [];
$.each(filtrados, function(i, item) {
  customList[i] = item;
});
```

con eso obtendrás lo que necesitas.

Saludos